# copy an object doesn't effect on my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, clone

I suppose to copy a object `source`, while `copy` changes, `source`should not change.The source code goes as follow:

```
layoutTreemap: function(source) {

    var copy = jQuery.extend(true,{},source);

    var select_polygon = this.get_selected_polygon();

    var vt = d3.layout.voronoitreemap()

    var layoutNodes = vt(copy);

    return layoutNodes;
}

d3.layout.voronoitreemap = function() {
    var hierarchy = d3.layout.hierarchy().sort(null),
    root_polygon = [[0,0],[500,0],[500,500],[0,500]], 
    iterations = 100,
    somenewvariable = 0;

    function voronoitreemap(d, depth) {
    var nodes = hierarchy(d),
    root = nodes[0];

    root.polygon = root_polygon;
    root.site = null;

    if (depth != null){
        max_depth = depth;
    }
    else{
        max_depth = "Infinity";
    }

    computeDiagramRecursively(root, 0);

    return nodes;
    }

    function computeDiagramRecursively(node, level) {
    var children = node.children;
    if(node.parent) node.parent = null;


    if (children && children.length && level < max_depth) {
        node.sites = VoronoiTreemap.init(node.polygon, node);  // can't say dataset, how about node?
        VoronoiTreemap.normalizeSites(node.sites);
        VoronoiTreemap.sites = node.sites;
        VoronoiTreemap.setClipPolygon(node.polygon);
        VoronoiTreemap.useNegativeWeights = false;
        VoronoiTreemap.cancelOnAreaErrorThreshold =  true;
        var polygons = VoronoiTreemap.doIterate(iterations);

        // set children polygons and sites
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        children[i].polygon = polygons[i];
        children[i].site = VoronoiTreemap.sites[i];

        computeDiagramRecursively(children[i], (level + 1));

        }

    }
    }
    ....

    return d3_layout_hierarchyRebind(voronoitreemap, hierarchy); 
}
```

But after execute `vt(copy)`, the `source` has been changed.

Comment: Explain  `doesn't work`

Comment: Your jsFiddle demo clearly shows that `$.extend` works (i.e. both objects are different). So the problem is likely with your code, not with `$.extend`. Please edit the title of your question to reflect the actual issue.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sg1e6cct/1/ - it is working

Comment: Your example code includes things that are not necessary for this issue. Try to reduce the amount of code to the smallest possible that still shows the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This gives issues

```
root.polygon = root_polygon;
children[i].polygon = polygons[i];
```

You are copying arrays you think. but actually you are copying the reference to the array. now you have two pointers to the same object(imagine two people using the same fork at dinner)

You need to change this into

```
root.polygon = root_polygon.slice();
children[i].polygon = polygons[i].slice();
```

this way the array gets copied instead of referenced. Now each dinner guest has its own fork.